# automatic upload of a file to input type='file'

Tags: javascript

i have this html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<input type="file" />
</body>
</html>
```

it looks like this image:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/aBHfs.jpg
but i want it like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/IUVNt.jpg
,
i.e:i want the file file.txt automatically uploaded into the input type='file' element. can u modify it in such a way?

Comment: Usually uploading files requires server to handle the upload. Your description doesn't tell us much about your environment. You can't upload into a html file input form element either (usually uploading happens when you submit the form). Please be more specific.

Comment: What is your goal? Automatic uploading a file in the browser without user permission? If so, you can't

Answer (score -2):

Check this sample:
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_enctype.asp

Modify the action to fit your program.